# (Lua) Doing mathematical operations with non-number values

Tags: lua

I want to make some sort of a Vector3 library for Lua which could let you make simple 3D position operations with simple syntax. I'll mention that I'm using Luaj for running Lua code for Java manipulation.

Here's my beginning code:

```
Vector3 = {
new = function (x1, y1, z1)
  return {x = x1, y = y1, z = z1}
end
}



Position1 = Vector3.new(1, 5, 8)
Position2 = Vector3.new(4, 7, 2)
```

And here's what I want to be able to happen:

```
Subtraction = Position1 - Position2
print(Subtraction.x, Subtraction.y, Subtraction.z) -- prints "-3, -2, 6"
```

Any idea on making EXACT code to work?

Comment: You should define __sub metamethod.

Comment: THANKS! This is definetly the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what metatables and metamethods are for. You should have a read [in the documentation](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.html).

Basically, they let you redefine what operators (and some other things) do on your values. What you want right now is to define the `__sub` metamethod, which defines how to handle the `-` operator. I guess in the future you'll want to redefine the other metamethods as well.

First, define a subtraction function in your `Vector3` "class" that takes two vectors:

```
function Vector3.subtract(u,v)
    return Vector3.new(u.x - v.x, u.y - v.y, u.z - v.z)
end
```

Then create let `Vector3` know the metatable it should give all vectors:

```
Vector3.mt = {__sub = Vector3.subtract}
```

And when you create a new vector:

```
new = function (x1, y1, z1)
    local vec = {x = x1, y = y1, z = z1}
    setmetatable(vec, Vector3.mt)
    return vec
end
```

You could also make the metatable (`mt`) a local variable inside your `new` function - that would prevent external code from messing with the metatable (as it would be only accessible by your `new` function). However, having it inside `Vector3` allows you to check against usages like `v - "string"`:

```
function Vector3.subtract(u,v)
    if getmetatable(u) ~= Vector3.mt or
       getmetatable(v) ~= Vector3.mt then
        error("Only vectors can be subtracted from vectors", 2)
    end
    return Vector3.new(u.x - v.x, u.y - v.y, u.z - v.z)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
Vector3 = {}

mt = {}

function Vector3:new(_x, _y, _z)
  return setmetatable({
    x = _x or 0, 
    y = _y or 0,
    z = _z or 0
  }, mt)
end

mt.__sub = function(v1, v2) return Vector3:new(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y, v1.z - v2.z) end
mt.__tostring = function(v) return "Vector3=(" .. v.x .. "," .. v.y .. "," .. v.z .. ")" end
mt.__index = Vector3 -- redirect queries to the Vector3 table

-- test Vector3
Position1 = Vector3:new(1, 5, 8)
Position2 = Vector3:new(4, 7, 2)
Sub = Position1 - Position2
print(Sub)
```

which would print:

```
Vector3=(-3,-2,6)
```

More on Lua & OO, see: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial